# Can't access div inside div

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` inside another `<div id="redBox">` that I want to `display: inline-block` when the user hovers over a `img`. Like this:

```
img.icnLocation:hover ~ .div_icnStamp.icnLocation {
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

For some reason, this div becomes inaccessible when it's inside the `<div id="redBox">`.

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4XAJ/2/) to see what I mean. I need to do this purely through CSS, no jQuery unfortunately. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), and that second div isn't a sibling, but the `#redBox` div it's in is.

You can use `img.icnLocation:hover ~ #redBox .div_icnStamp.icnLocation`:

```
img.icnLocation:hover ~ .div_icnStamp.icnLocation, img.icnLocation:hover ~ #redBox .div_icnStamp.icnLocation {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/W4XAJ/16/)**

Comment: Awesome! I discovered it was a general sibling selector as well.  I tried but failed because I didnt use the comma that you are using.  Just curious, why is the comma needed there?

Comment: Yes, this worked splendidly, thank you! So the tilde really requires you to specify each descendent as you go down to select the element that you really want. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Also to answer @matthew-a-mcfarland, the comma is there to make sure both instances of `<div class="div_icnStamp icnLocation">` inside *and* outside the box are selected.